# yii2 url managment/ correct registration of css and js files in a view

Tags: registration, yii2, yii-url-manager, url-mapping

I've urlmanager turned on, and probably because of this fact I cannot register css and js fiels properly.

when I add `$this->registerCssFile('views/A_view/A.css');`
my file is attached `<link href="D:\XAMPP\htdocs\somedomain.com/views/A_view/A.css" rel="stylesheet">`
which seems correct.
But the file is not really working on page.
Further more if I'm trying to open it from debug of chrome in a new window browser goes to

```
http://somedomain.com/A_view/D:/XAMPP/htdocs/somedomain.com/views/A_view/A.css
```

Probably I have problems in url managment ? 
In urlManager settings I've got such rules like:

```
A_view/<username:\w+> => A_view/view
A_view => A_view/index
A_view/custom => A_view/custom
views/A_view => views/A_view
```

Shall I add something ?

Comment: **This has nothing to do with url manager**, you should simply publish your assets before registering it, you could create an asset bundle for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As soju commented, it doesn't really have much to do with the urlmanager.

It would be better to register your css and js files in an [asset bundle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html), but you could also do:

```
$this->registerCssFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/views/A_view/A.css');
```

Comment: Problem is that I want to add custom js and css files for some views, and for some views no.

Comment: also this $this->registerCssFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/views/A_view/A.css');  makes correct url but css is not opening in this way. only if I open it with absolute path it opens d:/work/xampp/htdocs........

Comment: so can I use asset bundle to add css and js files to some views that I like ?

Comment: where are your css and js files? if they are in the Yii view folders, then it will indeed not work.

Comment: Well then I've put them in web/assets/ but they don't work anyway.

Comment: you dont need to put anything in the assets folder, yii does that for you. put css files in the `css` folder in your `web` folder and change the path in the `registerCssFile` method.

Comment: Ok. puting A.css inside /web/css file.
Registering $this->registerCssFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/web/css/A.css');
But problem stays the same :(

Comment: When I'm debuggin page I get this in head
<link href="/web/css/A.css" rel="stylesheet"> That's the place where the file is, but it still not working. And if I'm trying to open it in a new window from debug menu I receive yii error page Not Found (#404)
Unable to resolve the request "web/css/A.css".

Comment: Remember that your bootstrap file `index.php` in is in the web folder. `baseUrl` returns the folder that the bootstrap file is in, so try `$this->registerCssFile(Yii::$app->request->baseUrl.'/css/A.css');`

Answer (score 2):

To complement the other answer, these days you can also use `@web`:

```
$this->registerCssFile('@web/views/A_view/A.css');
```

It makes the code a little bit cleaner.